# Two while loops behaving strangely, Bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to Bash scripting. I have written a script to help me get some info using ssh from bunch of servers. the IP address of first set of devices are from 101 to 148, and the other set are from 201 to 210.

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE=192.168.11
SD_START=101
SD_END=148
HD_START=201
HD_END=210
SD_counter=$SD_START
HD_counter=$HD_START

while [[ $SD_counter -le $SD_END ]]
do 
    ip=$BASE.$SD_counter
    ssh $ip command1
    SD_counter=$(($SD_counter +1))

    if [ "$SD_counter"==148 ]
    then

        while [[ $HD_counter -le $HD_END ]]
        do
            ip=$BASE.$HD_counter

            ssh $ip command2
            HD_counter=$(($HD_counter +1))
        done
    fi 

done > log_SD_HD

echo "Done!"
```

But for some reason command1 is executed on 192.168.11.101 first, then command2 is executed on ip range 192.168.11.201-192.168.11.210 which is the second while loop.
After that the first while loop continues till the end. 
Why is this happening? I want the first while loop to be done before the second while loop. Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, `(( SD_counter <= SD_END ))` is easier to write and easier to read than `[[ $SD_counter -le $SD_END ]]`

Comment: Why don't you use two `while` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@0x1cf's answer provides the right pointer:

`[ "$SD_counter"==148 ]` doesn't work as expected.

Specifically: `"$SD_counter"==148`, based on bash's string synthesizing rules, is expanded to a *single string literal*: the value of `$SD_counter` is concatenated with literal `==148`, and the resulting *string literal* is treated as a Boolean.
Since a non-empty string in a Boolean context always evaluates to `true`, **`[ "$SD_counter"==148 ]` always evaluates to `true` due to lack of spaces around the `==`**.

Aside from that: in bash you should use `[[ ... ]]` rather than `[ ... ]` - it is more robust and provides more features.

Also note (as @0x1cf notes too) that - **if** using `[ ... ]` or `[[ ... ]]` - using the **arithmetic operators** is the right choice when **dealing with numbers**: `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, or `-ge`.

Generally, though, using `(( ... ))` expressions - **arithmetic *evaluation*** - provides **more flexibility with numbers** - see below.

---

That said, **your code can be greatly simplified** by using **arithmetic evaluation** - `(( ... ))` (see section `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` in `man bash`):

It allows you to use **C-style arithmetic and Boolean expressions**.
If we combine this with bash's ***array* variables**, your code can be simplified to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

BASE=192.168.11

START_INDICES=( 101 201 )
END_INDICES=( 148 210 )

COMMANDS=( command1 command2 )

numRanges=${#START_INDICES[@]}

for (( range = 0; range < numRanges; ++range )); do
  cmd=${COMMANDS[range]}
  for (( i=${START_INDICES[range]}; i<=${END_INDICES[range]}; ++i )); do
    ip=$BASE.$i
    ssh $ip $cmd
  done
done > log_SD_HD
```

Note:

- `(( ... ))` expressions DIFFER from normal bash assignments and conditionals in that you:

  - need NOT reference variables with `$`
  - need NOT double-quote variable references
  - you MAY have spaces around the assignment operator (`=`)
  - you MAY omit spaces around relational operators: `(( SD_counter==148 ))` DOES work.
- `( string1 ... )` creates an array with elements `string1`, `...`; `${#arrayVar[@]}` returns the count of elements of array variable `arrayVar`; `${arrayVar[ndx]}` returns the element with (`0`-based) index `ndx`.
- It's better to avoid ALL-UPPERCASE variable names such as `BASE`, as they may conflict with environment variables, which are by convention typically all-uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to nest the loops from what you showed:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE=192.168.11
SD_START=101
SD_END=148
HD_START=201
HD_END=210
SD_counter=$SD_START
HD_counter=$HD_START

while [[ $SD_counter -le $SD_END ]]
do 
    ip=$BASE.$SD_counter
    ssh $ip command1
    SD_counter=$(($SD_counter +1))
done> log_SD_HD
while [[ $HD_counter -le $HD_END ]]
do
    ip=$BASE.$HD_counter
    ssh $ip command2
    HD_counter=$(($HD_counter +1))
done>> log_SD_HD

echo "Done!"
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. Sorry for a trivial question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no reason to nest the loops from what you showed.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

*Hint*: You can always use `#!/bin/bash -x` to trace and debug your scripts.

---

Maybe using two `while` loop is a good idea, just as V_Maenolis showed. However, to answer your question about what's wrong with your script, try this

Replace

```
if [ "$SD_counter"==148 ]
```

with

```
if [ "$SD_counter" -gt 148 ]
```

which works for me.

So there are two errors

1. There should be a space before and after `==` operator, that is to say, using `A == B` NOT `A==B`
2. The logic of comparing `SD_counter == 148` is incorrect. Because when SD_counter hits 148, your script will run into the second while loop, and you'll get `147, 201, ..., 210, 148`. Using `-gt` instead avoids the problem.

Comment: that fixed the issue with the original script. another stupid question what does -gt do?

Comment: @user2617731 `-gt` means greater than. You can refer to `man test`.